# copying files using a batch script throws a syntax error

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, scripting

I have the following batch script and when I run it, it throws an error:

```
@echo Off
cls
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I

set datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%

set AGFILE=C:\vendor\My Work\file.txt"
if exist %AGFILE% 
(
echo "file exists"
copy %AGFILE% %AGFILE%.%datetime%
)
```

when I run the script, I get a syntax error. How do I fix the syntax error at the copy part?

Comment: There is also the opening quote `"` missing in the `set AGFILE`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
if exist %AGFILE% 
(
echo "file exists"
copy %AGFILE% %AGFILE%.%datetime%
)
```

But that is a syntax error. The action taken by `IF` when true must be on the same line as the `IF` token. This is easy to fix:

```
if exist %AGFILE% (
  echo "file exists"
  copy %AGFILE% %AGFILE%.%datetime%
)
```

Which works because `(` begins a compound statement, and just beginning it on the same line as the `IF` is sufficient. Similarly, if you need to use `ELSE` in code like this, it generally needs to be written `) ELSE (` all on one line.

Comment: That helped me move forward the IF statement. Now I don't get any errors, but the file just doesn't get copied. If I don't use variables, then I see that the file gets copied

Comment: If I use xcopy, it may work, but I keep getting the prompt to specify if its a file or a directory. This script will be run as an automated backup script and I cant have a user type anything at the prompt :|

Comment: sorry...I had the incorrect folder names in the variable. But RBerteig's correction on the IF syntax was one of the bigger problems.